# Save file dialog to save txt from array of numbers

Tags: c++, c++builder, vcl, tsavedialog

I would save my 2 arrays of ints and floats respectively into a "csv style" .txt file using a TSaveTextFileDialog. I am trying to do that in C++ Builder with a Windows VCL application.
This is my attempt:

```
__fastcall TForm6::TForm6(TComponent* Owner)
    : TForm(Owner)
{
    saveTxtDlg = new TSaveTextFileDialog(this);

    TStrings* encodings = new TStringList();

    encodings->AddObject("UTF8", TEncoding::UTF8);

    saveTxtDlg->Encodings->Assign(encodings);

    saveTxtDlg->Filter = "Text files (*.txt)|*.TXT";
}
```

```
void __fastcall TForm6::Button2Click(TObject *Sender)
{
    if (saveTxtDlg->Execute(this->Handle))
    {
        String filename = saveTxtDlg->FileName + ".txt";

        int encIndex = saveTxtDlg->EncodingIndex;

        TEncoding* enc = dynamic_cast<TEncoding*>
            (saveTxtDlg->Encodings->Objects[encIndex]);

        int x[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
        float y[] = {10.1, 20.5, 30.8, 40.7, 50.2};

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            std::string s = std::to_string(x[i]) + "," + std::to_string(y[i]);
            s.SaveToFile(filename, enc);

        }

    }
}
```

But *string* has no member for "SaveToFile". How could I solve, please? Thank you in advance.

Comment: You are leaking your `TStringList` object.  You need to `delete` it after `Assign()`'ing it to the dialog. Otherwise, you could just get rid of it completely and just use `saveTxtDlg->Encodings->AddObject(_D("UTF8"), TEncoding::UTF8);` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dialog merely gives you filenames that the user has selected. You are responsible for actually opening those files and writing your data to them as needed.

For instance, have a look at things like [`TStringList::SaveToFile()`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.TStringList), [`TFile::WriteAllText()`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.IOUtils.TFile.WriteAllText)/[`WriteAllLines()`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.IOUtils.TFile.WriteAllLines), [`TStreamWriter::Write()`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/System.Classes.TStreamWriter.Write)/[`WriteLine()`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/System.Classes.TStreamWriter.WriteLine), etc.

Try something like this:

```cpp
void __fastcall TForm6::Button2Click(TObject *Sender)
{
    if (saveTxtDlg->Execute(this->Handle))
    {
        String filename = saveTxtDlg->FileName;

        int encIndex = saveTxtDlg->EncodingIndex;

        TEncoding* enc = static_cast<TEncoding*>(saveTxtDlg->Encodings->Objects[encIndex]);

        int x[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
        float y[] = {10.1, 20.5, 30.8, 40.7, 50.2};

        TStringList *txt = new TStringList;

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
            String s = String(x[i]) + _D(",") + String(y[i]);
            txt->Add(s);
        }

        txt->SaveToFile(filename, enc);
        delete txt;
    }
}
```

Alternatively:

```cpp
#include <System.IOUtils.hpp>

void __fastcall TForm6::Button2Click(TObject *Sender)
{
    if (saveTxtDlg->Execute(this->Handle))
    {
        String filename = saveTxtDlg->FileName;

        int encIndex = saveTxtDlg->EncodingIndex;

        TEncoding* enc = static_cast<TEncoding*>(saveTxtDlg->Encodings->Objects[encIndex]);

        int x[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
        float y[] = {10.1, 20.5, 30.8, 40.7, 50.2};

        TStringDynArray txt;
        txt.Length = 5;

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
            String s = String(x[i]) + _D(",") + String(y[i]);
            txt[i] = s;
        }

        TFile::WriteAllLines(filename, txt, enc);
    }
}
```

Alternatively:

```cpp
void __fastcall TForm6::Button2Click(TObject *Sender)
{
    if (saveTxtDlg->Execute(this->Handle))
    {
        String filename = saveTxtDlg->FileName;

        int encIndex = saveTxtDlg->EncodingIndex;

        TEncoding* enc = static_cast<TEncoding*>(saveTxtDlg->Encodings->Objects[encIndex]);

        int x[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
        float y[] = {10.1, 20.5, 30.8, 40.7, 50.2};

        TStreamWriter *txt = new TStreamWriter(filename, false, enc);

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
            String s = String(x[i]) + _D(",") + String(y[i]);
            txt->WriteLine(s);
        }

        txt->Flush();
        delete txt;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Remy Lebeau. This is the answer I was looking for.